# OSError: [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

Hi I have installed "**Anaconda3-4.3.1-Windows-x86_64**" in my desktop but i get below error when I run the command "**jupyter notebook**" from CMD.

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\my pc>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pr275959\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 5, in <"module">
   sys.exit(jupyter_core.command.main())
File "C:\Users\pr275959\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 186, in main
_execvp(command, sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\pr275959\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 104, in _execvp
    raise OSError('%r not found' % cmd, errno.ENOENT)
OSError: [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing anaconda,
create a new environment using the following command

`conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda`

Then active the environment using

`source activate yourenvname`

Now install jupyter

`conda install jupyter`

Then,run 
`jupyter-notebook`

Answer (score 1):

For me, just installing jupyter globally solved it:

```
 conda install jupyter
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me:

#### For Python 2

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter`

#### For Python 3

`pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter`

This should reinstall everything from PyPi. This should solve the problem as I think running pip install "ipython[notebook]" messed things up.

[View_source](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/127)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and was able to solve it by using the Anaconda prompt.

In cmd, when I ran jupyter notebook, I would get the error message "Jupyter is not recognized as an internal or external command." But the same code running in Anaconda prompt would launch the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Anaconda 3.X in Windows and getting an error `"Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2"` when you run `pyspark --master local[*]`

Try,

```
pip install jupyter
```

and then run `pyspark --master local[*]`