# Create jupyter qtconsole shortcut installed on virtualenv on windows [7]

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, jupyter, qtconsole

This is how I am currently doing **and is working fine**.

```
C:\Users\me> dev\Scripts\activate
(dev) C:\Users\me> jupyter qtconsole --style monokai
```

I tried saving the above commands to `.bat` and double clicking the same.
The prompt opens and close.

I even tried.

```
C:\Users\me\dev\Scripts\jupyter.exe qtconsole --style monokai

>Error executing Jupyter command 'qtconsole': [Errno 'jupyter-qtconsole' not found] 2
```

cmd /k C:\Users\me\dev\Scripts\activate && jupyter qtconsole --style monokai
only activates virtualenv.

It fails too. Is there anything missing?

Comment: So what is the error when you run it from cmdline as per your first example?

Comment: I just included the error above.

Comment: How did you install `jupyter`?

Comment: `python -m venv dev;dev\scripts\activate;pip install qtconsole` Jupyter was installed as qtconsole dependency. as I said, by activating virtualenv the qtconsole just works fine.

Comment: But maybe the environment is not available globally?

Comment: Cannot check as I am not on my own PC, but at work, but perhaps check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848814/oserror-errno-jupyter-notebook-not-found-2)

Comment: looks like I have traped myself in x,y issue here. jupyter is working fine. I can call it by activating the virtualenv. but I am not able to create shortcut for it.

Comment: Don't double-click the `.bat` file, open a Command Prompt window and run the batch file by typing its path/name; you will see any error messages then; I'm quite sure it's some kind of path issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `jupyter-qtconsole.exe` in `your_env\Scripts`. You can create new shortcut giving that path with optional arguments.

In my case, I right clicked on where I wanted shortcut, selected `New>Shortcut` and in the dialogue box that appeared in the target put `C:\Users\me\dev\Scripts\jupyter-qtconsole.exe --style monokai` saved it and voila.